# Extend a delegate defined in a protocol with another protocol

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to extend a protocol delegate with another protocol as follows:

```
protocol WriteableCallback: class {
  ...
}

protocol Writeable {
  weak var delegate: WriteableCallback? { get set }
}

protocol NetworkWriteablecallback: WriteableCallback {
  ...
}

protocol NetworkWriteable: Writeable {
  ..
}
```

Now implementing the NetworkWriteable is fairly straight forward:

```
final class DefaultNetworkWriteable: NetworkWriteable {
   weak var delegate: NetworkWriteablecallback? 
   //type 'DefaultNetworkWriteable' does not conform to protocol 'Writeable
   //because delegate should be of type 'Writeablecallback'
}
```

If i write

```
weak var delegate: Writeablecallback?
```

everything compiles and works fine except that i can't call methods of NetworkWriteablecallback directly. I know, if i downcast the delegate like follows

```
if let delegate = delegate as? NetworkWriteablecallback {
 ...
}
```

than it works fine but casting isn't a good approach.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [you can't "override"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585572/how-to-use-multiple-protocols-in-swift-with-same-protocol-variables) the `delegate` requirement declaration, and if you could I don't know that it would be a good thing.

I would provide a convenience for transparently casting the delegate. And with protocol extensions, this casting becomes an innate behavior of the `NetworkWriteable` protocol.

```
extension NetworkWriteable {
    var networkWriteableDelegate: NetworkWriteablecallback? {
        set {
            delegate = newValue
        }
        get {
            return delegate as? NetworkWriteablecallback
        }
    }
}

final class DefaultNetworkWriteable: NetworkWriteable {

    weak var delegate: WriteableCallback?

    func myfunc() {
        if self.networkWriteableDelegate === self.delegate {
            // always true
        }
    }
}
```